# Convert sql to LINQ query for selection of multiple max columns in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

```
SELECT MAX(sectionid) AS SectionId,MAX(displayorder) AS DisplayOrder,propertyid AS PropertyId,1 AS IsSpecSection FROM (
    SELECT mp.SectionId ,mp.DisplayOrder ,mp.PropertyId  FROM 
   ModelProperties mp 
    INNER JOIN PropertySections PS ON mp.SectionId = 
     ps.SectionId 
WHERE ps.IsSpecSection = 1  )s 
GROUP BY propertyid
```

I want to convert above query into LINQ, able to do it for selection of single max column but not for multiple.

Comment: Can you share the codes that you already wrote

Comment: you have working SQL code; *why* do you want to convert it to LINQ?; also - possible duplicate: [Return multiple aggregate columns in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264737/return-multiple-aggregate-columns-in-linq)

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we can see where *specifically* you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code you have to modify the code as you need

```
using (var dbContext = new YourEntityName())
            {
                var result = (from mp in dbContext.ModelProperties
                              join ps in dbContext.PropertySections on mp.SectionId equals ps.SectionId
                              where ps.IsSpecSection = 1
                              group a by new { propertyid } into g
                              select sectionid , MAX(displayorder)AS DisplayOrder,propertyid AS PropertyId, 1 AS IsSpecSection).ToList();
```

}

[Max value in Linq select Within Innerjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219129/max-value-in-linq-select-within-innerjoin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
var list=(from mp in ModelProperties
          join ps in PropertySections on mp.SectionId equals ps.SectionId 
          where ps.IsSpecSection == 1
          group  new { mp, ps } by new { mp.PropertyId } into mgrp
          from grp in mgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()  
          select new
          { 
             grp.mp.SectionId, 
             grp.mp.PropertyId,
             grp.mp.DisplayOrder,
             grp.ps.IsSpecSection
          }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.SectionId).First();
```

This query helps you to retrieve `ModelProperties` rows that has matching `SectionId` in `PropertySections` and `IsSpecSection` has the value 1. Matching rows are then grouped by `PropertyId`. `OrderByDescending` sort the retrieved results in descending order of `SectionId`. `First()` retrieve the rows that has maximum `SectionId` for each `PropertySections` as the rows are sorted in descending order of `SectionId`.